# Pass all properties down to an element for writing wrapper components

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript

How does one pass all properties down in Angular similarly to React to write wrapper components?

How would you do the same as below for an Angular example?

```
const InputWithDefaultValue = (props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    return <input {...props} defaultValue="SomeRandomValue" />;
}
```

Comment: what exactly your need?

Comment: I want to create some wrapper components that edit the looks or some functionalities of a Button/Input while allowing all other functionalities remaining intact. For example user can use my custom input as they would use a normal input but it will have some extra functinality/ look.

Comment: Okay. have you tried using `@Input` and `@Output` directives?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question. The html input element has many properties like value, class etc. How do you pass all these properties down in angular without writing all of them explicitly.

Comment: Interesting... Please post here, if you found something.